# NextJS Continuous Deployment on Cloud Run not working

Tags: next.js, gcloud

I am trying default next js app on github to be auto deployed on Google Cloud Run, but it gets stuck in Building and Deploying step:
[Depploying Revision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmvoG.png)

I have tried using both docker image and default nodejs repository.

Not sure how can this be fixed.

This is the Error I am seeing in Cloud Build:
Your build failed to run: generic::invalid_argument: if 'build.service_account' is specified, the build must either (a) specify 'build.logs_bucket', (b) use the REGIONAL_USER_OWNED_BUCKET build.options.default_logs_bucket_behavior option, or (c) use either CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY / NONE logging options

I have tried granting IAM permissions for storage bucket to Cloud Build & Run